# "qemu-nbd --create" without sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, qemu

I'm working on a custom OS, and the `make` recipe I wrote for creating a new disk image requires `sudo` for connecting/disconnecting the virtual HDD image to a `/dev/nbdN` device. Because I don't want `sudo` in the recipe, I've just been using `sudo make disk`.

I thought I could just add myself to the `disk` group (as `stat /dev/nbd0` shows the UID of the file is `root`, and GID is `disk`) so I could attach and detach the `/dev/nbdN` devices without `sudo`, but it still doesn't work (yes, I've logged out and logged back in, and `id` shows me in group `disk`).

Do I still have to be `root` for `ioctl` calls to succeed (this is where it seems to fail if I'm not `root`)? Or is there something else specific to `qemu-nbd` that I need to do to avoid having use `root`?

**Edit:** my command is this (I have R/W permissions for `hda.qcow2`):

```
$ qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 hda.qcow2
```

And the output is this:

```
/build/buildd/qemu-2.0.0+dfsg/nbd.c:nbd_init():L504: Failed to set NBD socket
/build/buildd/qemu-2.0.0+dfsg/nbd.c:nbd_receive_request():L638: read failed
```

Running the same command with `sudo` executes successfully with no output.

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Comment: What command(s) are you exactly running and what is the exact error that qemu-nbd gives you?

Comment: @agtoever updated

Comment: Is the nbd module already inserted into the kernel? Maybe you just need root to insmod it and then group disk to actually attach it to the /dev/ndb* device.

Comment: @Steve nbd module is already loaded

Answer (score 3):

Here’s my non-straightforward solution: *don’t* connect `qemu-nbd` to the kernel NBD driver. Even when it works, it can be quite fragile: I managed to trap a couple of processes in the dreaded ‘uninterruptible sleep’ state this way. (Probably a race condition somewhere.)

Instead, use `nbdfuse` from the [nbdkit](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit) project. With `nbdfuse`, you can make the contents of the image available via a virtual file node under a directory of your choice. Here’s how to use it:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
nbdfuse ~/tmp/image --socket-activation qemu-nbd hda.qcow2 &
```

The image is now available at `~/tmp/image`. If you want to access a specific partition, you can achieve this by filtering the NBD connection through `nbdkit`:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
qemu-nbd --socket="$PWD/qemu-img.sock" hda.qcow2 &
nbdfuse ~/tmp/part1 --command \
    nbdkit -s nbd socket=qemu-nbd.sock \
    --filter=partition partition=1 &
```

This makes the partition available at `~/tmp/part1`.

When you’re done with the image, use `fusermount -u` on the directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` (see [nbd_ioctl()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e3a00f68e426df24a5fb98956a1bd1b23943aa1e/drivers/block/nbd.c#L724)), e.g. by granting it to the binary: `setcap 'cap_sys_admin=ep' qemu-nbd` - although `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is basically root.